# Join with default values but not wanting a cross product

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm joining two tables on three fields. The problem I'm having is that I need to use a default row from table b if a.baz is not in b.baz. The problem is some will have a match in b but also have a default and that is causing a cross-product that I don't want.

```
select a.foo, a.bar, a.baz, b.fee, b.fie
from a
join b
on a.foo = b.foo
and a.bar = b.bar
and ((a.baz = b.baz) or b.baz = 'DEFAULT')
```

Current output:

```
foo  bar  baz   fee   fie 
bob  doe  NYC   500   200 
bob  doe  DEFUALT 100 100 
john doe  DEFAULT 100 100 
jane doe  NYC   500   500
```

desired output:

```
foo  bar  baz   fee   fie 
bob  doe  NYC   500   200 
john doe  DEFAULT 100 100 
jane doe  NYC   500   500
```

Sample data:

`a:  foo  bar  baz
     bob  doe  NYC
     john doe  NYC
     jane doe  NYC`

`b:  foo bar baz fee fie
     bob doe NYC 500 200
     bob doe DEFAULT 100 100
     john doe CHI 300 200
     john doe DEFAULT 100 100
     jane doe NYC 500 100`

Comment: can you show some sample data from the tables?

Comment: Added some sample data.

Comment: the result you get is not a cross product. i guess your current output is correct, with the conditions in question.

Comment: The query doesn't match the results. It is `a.baz` in your query, but `b.baz` in your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `NOT EXISTS` so as to exclude the `b` record having `baz = 'DEFAULT'` when a match `a.baz = b.baz` also exists:

```
select a.foo, a.bar, a.baz, b.baz, b.fee, b.fie
from a
join b
on a.foo = b.foo and a.bar = b.bar and ((a.baz = b.baz) OR b.baz = 'DEFAULT')
where not exists (select 1
                  from b as b1
                  where a.foo = b1.foo and
                        a.bar = b1.bar and 
                        b.baz = 'DEFAULT' and
                        b1.baz = a.baz)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77dab/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is quite fine, as it already contains the rows you want. Now you must must remove the unwanted rows. You do this by ranking your matches and only keeping the better match. This can be done with `ROW_NUMBER`, giving the better record row number 1.

```
select foo, bar, abaz, bbaz, fee, fie
from
(
  select 
    a.foo, a.bar, a.baz as abaz, b.baz as bbaz, b.fee, b.fie,
    row_number() over (partition by a.foo, a.bar 
                       order by case when b.baz = 'DEFAULT' then 2 else 1 end) as rn
  from a
  join b on b.foo = a.foo
         and b.bar = a.bar
         and b.baz in (a.baz, 'DEFAULT')
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way to solve this using outer joins:

```
select 
  a.foo, 
  a.bar, 
  case when b.baz is null then d.baz else b.baz end as baz,
  case when b.baz is null then d.fee else b.fee end as fee,
  case when b.baz is null then d.fie else b.fie end as fie
from a
left join b    on b.foo = a.foo and b.bar = a.bar and b.baz = a.baz
left join b d  on d.foo = a.foo and d.bar = a.bar and d.baz = 'DEFAULT';
```

If fee and fie are not nullable, you can simplify this to:

```
select 
  a.foo, 
  a.bar, 
  coalesce(b.baz, d.baz) as baz,
  coalesce(b.fee, d.fee) as fee,
  coalesce(b.fie, d.fie) as fie
from a
left join b    on b.foo = a.foo and b.bar = a.bar and b.baz = a.baz
left join b d  on d.foo = a.foo and d.bar = a.bar and d.baz = 'DEFAULT';
```